# Condition check in async method

Tags: c#, if-statement, async-await

Question description:
**I am surprised that code inside the if block is reached. I supposed the if block won't be executed.**

I am totally confused. Who can explain or teach me?

```
private async Task TestMethod()
{
    bool ok = false;
    City city = City.BJ;
    await Task.Delay(100);
    ok = true;

    if (!ok)//Suppose it won't go into this code block. Because variable 'ok' is true.
    {
        if (city == City.BJ)//City is enum type.
        {
            throw new Exception("BJ. Good day.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("SH. Rainy day");//This row is reached.Weird! But the upper caller method doesn't detect this exception.
        }
    }
}

enum City
{
    BJ = 1,
    SH = 2
}
```

Comment: If the caller doesn't "detect" the exception, how do you know that it executed it?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `if(!ok)` and you can reproduce the behavior

Comment: Which version of .NET and Visual Studio is this?

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce it, which is why I ask. I tried it in a console application in Visual Studio 2015 in .NET 4.6.1, I tried a Winforms application in the same, and I tried LINQPad, neither reproduced what you're seeing.

Comment: Are you sure `ok` isn't a global variable? This is *exactly* what your code looks like when you reproduce the problem? Can you show a screenshot of the breakpoint being hit?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with .NET 4.6.1, VS 2015, WPF. [image](http://imgur.com/a/dFIDe)

Comment: This is an artefact of the way the debugger is showing you the next line when you single-step through the code. It's not really executing that line.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, for me its true, the code isn't executed. Could you provide any link to read about it?

Comment: @Roma I can't find any links, but it's surely true - and it happens with VS2017 too! I imagine it's a small bug in the debugger.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, ok, thanks

Comment: OK, sorry, I put a breakpoint on the `throw` line, I can reproduce this too now. I agree with @MatthewWatson, this is a bug in the debugger, not in the C# compiler or the runtime. This should be reported through [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

Comment: The reason for this oddity is that the compiler has merged the prologue of this method due to there not being any more code to execute. There seems to be some information not being emitted since the instruction it jumps to in order to skip the if-statement is being tied to the line with the throw statement. Perhaps this is a compiler error after all.

Comment: Incidentally, you can reproduce this with only two lines of code in TestMethod(): `if (Environment.TickCount == -1) throw new Exception();`

Comment: I have reported a bug for this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3125763

Comment: This does in fact work as expected :: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lDpMkX)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, .NET 4.6.1, VS 2016, WPF

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I agree. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, sorry. FYI. The VS is 2015 Pro, not VS 2016.

Comment: Just mentioning that this is reproducible in LINQPad as well, which has debugging capabilities. It steps to the same line as Visual Studio which further enhances my belief that it is the compiler that is the culprit here. When rewriting code the compiler emits similar constructs as [#line directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34dk387t.aspx) which tells the compiler to emit debug information tying the generated/compiled code to specific source code lines. It seems it doesn't do this correctly here.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? he is the first one to ask????

Comment: @MosheD This question doesn't have an answer therefore it is not possible to close the other question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks, something new to learn!!!