# If (false == true) executes block when throwing exception is inside

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a rather strange problem that is occurring.

This is my code:

```
private async Task BreakExpectedLogic()
{
    bool test = false;
    if (test == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        throw new Exception("BAD HASH!");
    }
}
```

Seems really simple, it shouldn't hit the `Console.WriteLine` or the `throw`.
For some reason it's always hitting the `throw`.

If I move the `throw` into its own method then it works fine. My question is how is it ignoring the `if` block and hitting the `throw new Exception`:

[image: Here is some evidence]

**EDIT 1:** I've updated my code to include the signature, I've removed everything not related to this problem and ran it, it still happens.

Comment: Your evidence is a picture which shows that the compiler correctly complains that this `if` is never entered. I don't see that the exception is raised.

Comment: Did you re-compile your project?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the picture is it being debugged, the yellow highlight is where the code is at

Comment: I just created a blank core console app, pasted just your code into the `Main` and....surprise, norepro. Either you're mistaken or you've missed some important detail.

Comment: Is this in an `async` method by any chance? Because it seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528458/condition-check-in-async-method#comment72197638_42528458

Comment: I've recompiled, cleaned, reopened the project tried different ways of doing the if, but still the same

Comment: This would benefit from additional context, method signature, etc.

Comment: @George: still no evidence because you might use old debug symbols. Recompile in debug mode and then start again.

Comment: @TimSchmelter _I've recompiled, cleaned, reopened the project tried different ways of doing the if, but still the same_

Comment: @TimSchmelter unless VS is lying to me, yes.

Comment: @George: if you surround it in a `try-catch` you can catch this exception?

Comment: Are you throwing same exception anywhere else in application, it might be invoked from there?  OR `async` method as suggested by @MatthewWatson

Comment: There is a compiler error or warning at the if statement. What does it say? Are there any errors mentioned in the errors view?

Comment: I'm able to re-produce this on LinqPad 5.10, but only when the method is `async`. Also, it only happens when the `if` clause is the last block of the method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have enclosed it in a `try-catch`, seems like it's a duplicate of [This question mentioned by Matthew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528458/condition-check-in-async-method#comment72197638_42528458), it's just VS saying it's ran that line when in reality it hasn't

Comment: It's duplicate but cannot be marked as such because other question does not contain any answer.

Comment: usually when such happens to me I clean solution and rebuild sln.

Comment: isn't it duplicate of that question asked yesterday ?

Comment: @Evk Then couldn't we close the other one?

Comment: There is a very similar bug in VC++ -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574919/c-exception-skips-try-catch-clause-in-msvc-x64/19708664

Comment: I tried recreating this in today's release of **Visual Studio 2017 RTM** and cannot! Bug officially non-existent.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that *the code was compiled with some level of optimization so where the debugger is pointing is NOT where the execution is actually occurring.*  Suggest compiling with no optimization when debugging.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

It seems to be the bug in `async` method, the code **is not** actually executed but debugger steps to the line with `throw` statement. If there are some lines of code before `throw` statement inside `if` these lines are ignored, debugger steps **only** to the line with `throw` statement.

Also, if you don't use variable - `if (false)` or `if (true == false)` then debugger steps to the correct line of code - to the closing curly brace.

This bug has been posted by **@Matthew Watson** to Visual Studio team (link is not available now).

Also, see similar question - [Condition check in async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528458/condition-check-in-async-method)

**EDIT (2017-10-06):**

Issue cannot be reproduced in VS 2017 15.3.5 using .Net Framework 4.7. Seems like VS team has fixed this issue.

Comment: Thank you, without knowing this is a bug in the debugger I would of likely gone mad.

Comment: A bug in the debugger? How very meta.  :)  (singing *I never meta bug like this before...*)

Comment: @George I hope you don't mind, I've taken your sample and created a console app using it, and attached it to the VS issue Roma has linked to.

Comment: @Simba: Tell me you've never used a debugger to debug itself.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix of course not, anything that can help this issue get fixed is okay with me :)

Comment: Hmm.  It seems the bug could be in the debug info generated by the compiler rather than in the debugger itself.  I'll wait for MS to acknowledge the Connect bug before voting up or down.

Comment: @Joshua I have a debugger that only debugs programs that don't debug themselves. Question: does the debugger debug itself? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox

Comment: Still an issue in net standard 2.0, they did not learn from their mistakes.

Answer (score 11):

Just an addendum to the answer, I've recently encountered the same issue, and looked to the actual x86 code in the debugger, and it was generated in a weird way like this (simplified):

```
// if (...) {
0001: jne 0006
...
0006: jmp 0007
// }
0007: ret
```

So instead of directly jumping to the last instructions of the method, it does double jump, where I believe the second unconditional jump is mistakenly recognized as a part of the code inside `if` block.

So I would speculate that this bug might be related to JIT compiler.